# multiprocessing.Pipe is even slower than multiprocessing.Queue?

Tags: python

I tried to benchmark the speed up of `Pipe` over `Queue` from the `multiprocessing` package. T thought `Pipe` would be faster as `Queue` uses `Pipe` internally.

Strangely, `Pipe` is slower than `Queue` when sending large numpy array. What am I missing here?

Pipe:

```
import sys
import time
from multiprocessing import Process, Pipe
import numpy as np

NUM = 1000


def worker(conn):
    for task_nbr in range(NUM):
        conn.send(np.random.rand(400, 400, 3))
    sys.exit(1)


def main():
    parent_conn, child_conn = Pipe(duplex=False)
    Process(target=worker, args=(child_conn,)).start()
    for num in range(NUM):
        message = parent_conn.recv()


if __name__ == "__main__":
    start_time = time.time()
    main()
    end_time = time.time()
    duration = end_time - start_time
    msg_per_sec = NUM / duration

    print "Duration: %s" % duration
    print "Messages Per Second: %s" % msg_per_sec

# Took 10.86s.
```

Queue

```
import sys
import time
from multiprocessing import Process
from multiprocessing import Queue
import numpy as np

NUM = 1000

def worker(q):
    for task_nbr in range(NUM):
        q.put(np.random.rand(400, 400, 3))
    sys.exit(1)

def main():
    recv_q = Queue()
    Process(target=worker, args=(recv_q,)).start()
    for num in range(NUM):
        message = recv_q.get()

if __name__ == "__main__":
    start_time = time.time()
    main()
    end_time = time.time()
    duration = end_time - start_time
    msg_per_sec = NUM / duration

    print "Duration: %s" % duration
    print "Messages Per Second: %s" % msg_per_sec

# Took 6.86s.
```

Comment: I thinks it's wiser to move to Python3 anyhow, since Python2 is discontinued and your issue does not take place on Python3

Comment: @FabioVeronese Thanks. Do you have any benchmarks or pointers?

Comment: @FabioVeronese I see your answer below, thanks!

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You can do an experiment and put the following into your **Pipe** code above..

```
def worker(conn):
    for task_nbr in range(NUM):
        data = np.random.rand(400, 400, 3)
    sys.exit(1)

def main():
    parent_conn, child_conn = Pipe(duplex=False)
    p = Process(target=worker, args=(child_conn,))
    p.start()
    p.join()
```

This gives you the time that it takes to create the data for your test.  On my system this takes about 2.9 seconds.

Under the hood the `queue` object implements a buffer and a threaded send. The thread is still in the same process but by using it, the data creation doesn't have to wait for the system IO to complete.  It effectively parallelizes the operations.  Try your **Pipe** code modified with some simple threading implemented (disclaimer, code here is for test only and is not production ready)..

```
import sys
import time
import threading
from multiprocessing import Process, Pipe, Lock
import numpy as np
import copy

NUM = 1000

def worker(conn):
    _conn = conn
    _buf = []
    _wlock = Lock()
    _sentinel = object() # signal that we're done
    def thread_worker():
        while 1:
            if _buf:
                _wlock.acquire()
                obj = _buf.pop(0)
                if obj is _sentinel: return
                _conn.send(data)
                _wlock.release()
    t = threading.Thread(target=thread_worker)
    t.start()
    for task_nbr in range(NUM):
        data = np.random.rand(400, 400, 3)
        data[0][0][0] = task_nbr    # just for integrity check
        _wlock.acquire()
        _buf.append(data)
        _wlock.release()
    _wlock.acquire()
    _buf.append(_sentinel)
    _wlock.release()
    t.join()
    sys.exit(1)

def main():
    parent_conn, child_conn = Pipe(duplex=False)
    Process(target=worker, args=(child_conn,)).start()
    for num in range(NUM):
        message = parent_conn.recv()
        assert num == message[0][0][0], 'Data was corrupted'        

if __name__ == "__main__":
    start_time = time.time()
    main()
    end_time = time.time()
    duration = end_time - start_time
    msg_per_sec = NUM / duration

    print "Duration: %s" % duration
    print "Messages Per Second: %s" % msg_per_sec
```

On my machine this takes 3.4 seconds to run which is almost exactly the same as your **Queue** code above.

From https://docs.python.org/2/library/threading.html

*In Cython, due to due to the Global Interpreter Lock, only one thread can execute Python code at once... however, threading is still an appropriate model if you want to run multiple I/O-bound tasks simultaneously.*

The `queue` and `pipe` differences are definitely an odd implementation detail until you dig into it a bit.

Comment: Exactly what I'm looking for! The blocking feature of Connection makes it unsuitable to be placed in the main thread.

Comment: @bivouac0 In the docs quote it should be 'CPython' instead 'Cython'.

Answer (score 6):

I assume by your print command you are using Python2. However the strange behavior cannot be replicated with Python3, where `Pipe` is actually faster than `Queue`.

```
import sys
import time
from multiprocessing import Process, Pipe, Queue
import numpy as np

NUM = 20000


def worker_pipe(conn):
    for task_nbr in range(NUM):
        conn.send(np.random.rand(40, 40, 3))
    sys.exit(1)


def main_pipe():
    parent_conn, child_conn = Pipe(duplex=False)
    Process(target=worker_pipe, args=(child_conn,)).start()
    for num in range(NUM):
        message = parent_conn.recv()


def pipe_test():
    start_time = time.time()
    main_pipe()
    end_time = time.time()
    duration = end_time - start_time
    msg_per_sec = NUM / duration
    print("Pipe")
    print("Duration: " + str(duration))
    print("Messages Per Second: " + str(msg_per_sec))

def worker_queue(q):
    for task_nbr in range(NUM):
        q.put(np.random.rand(40, 40, 3))
    sys.exit(1)

def main_queue():
    recv_q = Queue()
    Process(target=worker_queue, args=(recv_q,)).start()
    for num in range(NUM):
        message = recv_q.get()

def queue_test():
    start_time = time.time()
    main_queue()
    end_time = time.time()
    duration = end_time - start_time
    msg_per_sec = NUM / duration
    print("Queue")
    print("Duration: " + str(duration))
    print("Messages Per Second: " + str(msg_per_sec))


if __name__ == "__main__":
    for i in range(2):
        queue_test()
        pipe_test()
```

Results in:

```
Queue
Duration: 3.44321894646
Messages Per Second: 5808.51822408
Pipe
Duration: 2.69065594673
Messages Per Second: 7433.13169575
Queue
Duration: 3.45295906067
Messages Per Second: 5792.13354361
Pipe
Duration: 2.78426194191
Messages Per Second: 7183.23218766


------------------
(program exited with code: 0)
Press return to continue
```

Comment: Not at my machine (Python 3.6) Queue
Duration: 5.491702318191528
Messages Per Second: 3641.8579961534033
Pipe
Duration: 6.707621812820435
Messages Per Second: 2981.6827123099774
Queue
Duration: 4.365077495574951
Messages Per Second: 4581.820144149738
Pipe
Duration: 6.05034065246582
Messages Per Second: 3305.5989982727647

Answer (score 2):

On my system `Pipe(duplex=False)` is slower (twice the time, or half the rate) than `Pipe(duplex=True)`. For anyone looking for performance here is a side-by-side comparison:

```py
from time import time
from multiprocessing import Process, Queue, Pipe

n = 1000
buffer = b'\0' * (1000*1000) # 1 megabyte

def print_elapsed(name, start):
    elapsed = time() - start
    spi = elapsed / n
    ips = n / elapsed
    print(f'{name}: {spi*1000:.3f} ms/item, {ips:.0f} item/sec')

def producer(q):
    start = time()
    for i in range(n):
        q.put(buffer)
    print_elapsed('producer', start)

def consumer(q):
    start = time()
    for i in range(n):
        out = q.get()
    print_elapsed('consumer', start)

class PipeQueue():
    def __init__(self, **kwargs):
        self.out_pipe, self.in_pipe = Pipe(**kwargs)
    def put(self, item):
        self.in_pipe.send_bytes(item)
    def get(self):
        return self.out_pipe.recv_bytes()
    def close(self):
        self.out_pipe.close()
        self.in_pipe.close()

print('duplex=True')
q = PipeQueue(duplex=True)
producer_process = Process(target=producer, args=(q,))
consumer_process = Process(target=consumer, args=(q,))
consumer_process.start()
producer_process.start()
consumer_process.join()
producer_process.join()
q.close()

print('duplex=False')
q = PipeQueue(duplex=False)
producer_process = Process(target=producer, args=(q,))
consumer_process = Process(target=consumer, args=(q,))
consumer_process.start()
producer_process.start()
consumer_process.join()
producer_process.join()
q.close()
```

Results:

```
duplex=True
consumer: 0.301 ms/item, 3317 item/sec
producer: 0.298 ms/item, 3358 item/sec
duplex=False
consumer: 0.673 ms/item, 1486 item/sec
producer: 0.669 ms/item, 1494 item/sec
```

I think this must come down to CPython [using `os.pipe` vs `socket.socketpair`](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/3.7/Lib/multiprocessing/connection.py#L510-L519), but I'm not sure.

Comment: Don't your results show that `duplex=True` (3358 item/sec) is 2 times faster than `duplex=False` (1494 item/sec)?

Comment: However in your first line you say `On my system Pipe(duplex=True) is slower than Pipe(duplex=False).`.